# Uniquely identify computer connected to Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Is there a way to uniquely identify the computer connected to my Arduino, say using a MAC address or something similar?

Assume I have some data stored on the EEPROM of my Arduino UNO, and my PC's MAC address is stored in the uploaded sketch. Now, I want to compare it with the MAC address of the connected PC, and if the two do not match, I clear the data stored on the EEPROM of the board (so that the currently connected PC isn't able to read it).

Is there any way to get the MAC address of the PC (or something similar) that can help me identify the PC uniquely?

Comment: connected which way? over USB it is not possible by design

Comment: using a USB cable

Comment: not possible by design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a custom-made Serial port program that runs on your different PCs, you could send some message to the Arduino after connecting. But just from Arduino and the Serial Monitor in the IDE, it is not possible.